# Unhandled exception type ParseException from comparator

Tags: java, sorting, date, compiler-errors, simpledateformat

I need to sort a list of `String`'s representing **dates**.

I tried the following code:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    Collections.sort(days,
            (s1, s2) -> sdf.parse(s1).compareTo(sdf.parse(s2)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But in Eclipse I get the compile-time error at `sdf.parse(s1)`:

> Unhandled exception type `ParseException`

Any solution?

My input list is:

```
[2016-01-02, 2016-01-03, 2016-01-01]
```

Comment: Can you not parse them *before* trying to compare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why the ParseException appears when use SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058499/why-the-parseexception-appears-when-use-simpledateformat)

Comment: If your dates are in the `YYYY-MM-dd` already you can sort them as they are without converting them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Date which is in string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java)

Comment: @SandipND I tried it but list is not sorted

Comment: Please give us input - probably you have wrong date format in the input data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: why can't I throw an exception in Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832755/java-why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-in-comparator)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). In addition `LocalDate.parse()` will parse your strings without any explicit formatter and isn’t declared to throw any exceptions, so you won’t have your issue.

Comment: As an aside, beware of the case of your format pattern letters. `yyyy` and `YYYY` mean different things. Check the documentation if in doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`SimpleDateFormat::parse` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) throws a [checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation), so you must catch it where the method is called - in this case, inside the lambda expression.

Another problem is that uppercase `Y` does **not** represent the year. [Check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): `Y` is the [**week year** field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), which is not always the same as the year. You must change it to lowercase `y`:

```
// use lowercase "y" for year
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Collections.sort(days, (s1, s2) -> {
    try {
        return sdf.parse(s1).compareTo(sdf.parse(s2));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // what to do when parse fails? just ignore and go on? throw exception?
    }
    return 0; // return something or throw exception?
});
```

But there are problems with this code: if a `ParseException` occurs, it means the `String` doesn't contain a date in the expected format (`yyyy-MM-dd`). What should you do in this case? Ignore it and return 0 as above (meaning that the [invalid string is "equal" to any date](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10)?). Stop the sorting and throw an exception?

Maybe it's better to first try to convert the strings to dates (and if you find an invalid string, you can decide to either ignore or stop the conversion), and just after that, when you're sure all elements are valid dates, you sort them.

#### Java date/time API

As you're using lambdas, your Java version is >= 8, so why not use the [new date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)?

Assuming that `days` is a collection of `String`'s:

```
List<LocalDate> sortedDates = days.stream()
    // parse to LocalDate
    .map(LocalDate::parse)
    // sort
    .sorted()
    // get list of LocalDate's
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case, any invalid `String` in `days` will make this code throw an exception and the sorting won't be done. The difference is that this method throws an **unchecked** exception, so you don't need to explicity catch it here, as you did with `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you want the `days` list sorted, though, just convert the `LocalDate` back to `String`:

```
days = days.stream()
    // parse to LocalDate
    .map(LocalDate::parse)
    // sort
    .sorted()
    // convert back to string
    .map(LocalDate::toString)
    // get list of String's
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that this is possible because `LocalDate::parse` return an unchecked exception. Or you would end up with the same problem with the `SimpleDateFormat`. Nice answer !

Comment: @AxelH Indeed, I updated that in the answer, thanks!

Comment: Very elegant java.time solution.